# Probability Revision, 4 selected from 10 but only 3 must match?

Tags: probability

I am revising for a test that I have a week from now and I have come across a question that I cannot foresee how to solve.

The question directly taken from my textbook is;

In a competition, 4 numbers are selected at random from the set A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} by the competition organisers. We can choose any 3 numbers from A and win if our set is contained in the set of 4 numbers picked by the organisers. What is the probability that we win?

I first tried to work out this problem by calculating the probability of having to pick four numbers correct, which I worked out to be 10*9*8*7/1*2*3*4 = 210. I then thought that by having to only get 3 numbers I could simply do 210*0.75 = 157.5, but this does not seem at all correct.

I tried to research the method of working out the odds of getting only 3 balls correct on a 6 ball lottery and such but all tutorials simply outline the odds of actually winning the jackpot!

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated (I would NOT like an answer to this question in the sense that I would still like to work it out myself).

Thanks,

Comment: the probability of winning is the probability of getting (4 out of 4  or 3 out of 4). You already found 4 out of 4. 3 out of four is just the same, only that one number is chosen from the "wrong" numbers. This can be done at the first selection, the second one, the third one or fourth one.

Comment: $\frac{4}{10}\cdot\frac{3}{9}\cdot\frac{2}{8}$

Comment: Thank you for your time and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** 1) In how many ways can the organisers choose $4$ numbers? 2) In how many ways can they choose $4$ numbers so that $3$ of the numbers match the $3$ that you picked?